# How to make dll with UIElement for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dll, windows-phone

I frequently load dll file and import namespace for instance

```
xmlns:UI="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;assembly=Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI"
```

and then create XAML element using it

```
  <UI:AdControl  .../>
```

Can anyone share a post where is described how to create such a useful dll?

Comment: If I understand your question, you are asking how to make a DLL that contains user controls. You may want to consider rewording your problem statenent to indicate that, as I *almost* thought you were asking for outside resources (which is off-topic). Just some friendly advice!

Answer (score 1):

You create this like any other DLL in .NET:

1. Create a "Library" project. There is a "User Control Library" in some versions of WPF, so you might as well use it, but I believe a standard "Class Library" will work just as well
2. Add a "UserControl" to your library. Make sure it is marked public!
3. From the project that will use this DLL, add a reference to the new library project
4. Create a `xmlns` line like the one you have, but mapped to your assembly and namespace
5. Use the UserControl, again just like you already have.

Nothing special really, it really is just like any other DLL project.

Comment: If you create UIElement there are distinctions, depending on platform etc.

Comment: @RichiR. Those distinctions being? Are you referring to potential differences in the "Class Library" template and the "User Control Library" template? I don't understand your comment, especially considering you asked the question.

Comment: When you want to create UIElement it has to derive from for instance FrameworkElement and so on. I just wanted to see some examples to get familiar with it.

Comment: @RichiR. If you use the "UserControl" template (highly recommended!) It already does that for you! Not sure how to give an example besides telling you to use what is given to you (btw, deriving from `UserControl` is much more common than `FrameworkElement`)

Comment: I wish I had an example. How would I make a Button with another elements inside, having influence on appearance and so on, and that's all closed in dll.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "influence on appearance" but the rest of it still sounds like a user control, or *maybe* a style that you could use via `MergedDictionary` (the style works if there is no code-behind, its just a different look for a standard `Button`). Either way, you *still* just create a normal DLL and reference it. From the code you posted though, you definitely want a `UserControl`.

Comment: What would you do if you wanted to have a button with several elements inside Content, styles for these all and so on. I want to enclose xaml file into dll so that I could create and object of its definition.

Comment: I have done. The only thing was to add this UserControl to .dll and it started working.

Comment: @RichiR. Thats what I was trying to suggest. Glad you got it working though. If you want to discuss it anymore, lets go to chat.